# Direct2D Coordinate erro

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, coordinate-systems, direct2d

I was doing a test program with direct2d to show lines, however I noticed a little detail and that is that when I tell direct2d to draw a dotted line (100,200) and (500,200), direct2d really isn't drawing the beginning of the line at the point (100,200), but it draws it one pixel less, that is, it coordinates at the coordinate (100,99). Does anyone know why this is? I checked this detail using direct2d without antialiasing mode and showing in the debug output the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Direct2D's own design.

To be precise, the coordinates of the line are from (99.5, 199.5) - (500.5, 200.5).

And [@Rick Brewster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773729/11128312) has explained these.

> When you give it a pixel coordinate such as (100, 120), that refers to
>   the top and left corner of the pixel element that spans from pixel
>   coordinates (100, 120) to (101, 121) (top/left are inclusive,
>   right/bottom are exclusive). Since it's a straight horizontal line you
>   are effectively getting a filled rectangle from (99.5, 119.5) -
>   (300.5, 120.5).

So if you want to draw a line from that covers the pixels (100, 200) to
(500, 200), you can use aliased rendering or use half-pixel offsets.

Comment: @FrancoCortes Glad to hear that. If my answer is useful to you, please mark it . This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Refer: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/646262)